# How to create different links links with c:url in jsp?

Tags: jsp, curl, href

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="/movie/${session.id}/details">
```

And my controller has something like

```
 @GetMapping("/movie/{id}/details")
 public ModelAndView showDetails(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {...}
```

Because some changes in the project, now I need to use c:url to create the links. But `c:url` is not working properly if I just do something like (I´m using `taglib core`).

```
<c:url value="/movie/${session.id}/details" var=myURL>
<a href="${myURL}"></a>
```

keep in mind that I don´t want to change my route (the url)
And it's not the same case when `id` goes as parameter

```
<c:url value="/admin/lugar" var="myURL">
        <c:param name="id" value="${sala.id}"/>
    </c:url>
    <c:import url="${myURL}" var="myURL2"/>
    <a href="${myURL2}"></a>
```

This second, the controller looks like this

```
@GetMapping("/admin/placeholder")
public ModelAndView form(@RequestParam("roomId") ) {...}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What language is the "controller" written in? Java?

Comment: Define "is not working properly". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: The controller is written in Java, and the URL fails to reach the controller method (the first java code expected to be reached after the request)